# How can MCollective replace a dead subscriber from an ActiveMQ queue?

Tags: activemq-classic

I have a problem using direct addressing with MCollective via ActiveMQ 5.8. (http://docs.puppetlabs.com/mcollective/deploy/middleware/activemq.html)

The problem arises when one of the nodes subscribed to the nodes queue via MCollective crashes and doesn't unsubscribe. When the host boots and subscribes again, there are now two subscribers with the same identity, because ActiveMQ doesn't recognize that the pre-crash one is no longer listening. This is a problem with direct addressing because it goes in the queue, ActiveMQ sends the message to only one subscriber, and it always seems to pick the one that's not listening; so the message is never delivered to the actual node. I can observe this happening if I have ActiveMQ log the message frames.

This may be related to the ActiveMQ concept of a "durable subscriber" (where a subscriber of the same identity unsubscribes any existing one) but I don't have any idea how that is configured from MCollective.

What I want is that either the new subscriber bumps the old, or that the dead subscriber is removed when a message is sent to it and the connection is dead (with Wireshark I can see the packets aren't ACKed, instead an ICMP packet returns "Destination unreachable").

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, according to http://projects.puppetlabs.com/issues/23365, the solution is to use MCollective 2.3 (I was using 2.2) and Stomp 1.1 keepalives.